# Creating table of contents on page that already has header IDs set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to make an automatic `ToC` that can be dropped on a page. All of the pages have `h3` tags with `id` set already. All of the code I'm finding wants to create the `id` for the tags first, but the pages I'm working on already have tags.

Basically I just need the code to

1. Step through all h3s on the page and get the ID and the text.
2. Create links to each of the h3s using the ID and text `<a href="#id">Text</a>`

Here's the code I've tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Get ToC div
    toc = document.getElementById("ToC"); //Add a header
    tocHeader = document.createElement("h2");
    tocHeader.innerText = "Table of contents";
    toc.appendChild(tocHeader); // Get the h3 tags — ToC entries

    $('h3').each(function() {
      var headers = $(this).attr('id');
      var name = $(this).text();
    });

    // For each h3
    for (i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
      tocListItem = document.createElement("li");
      // a link for the h3
      tocEntry = document.createElement("a");
      tocEntry.setAttribute("href", "#" + name);
      tocEntry.innerText = name[i];
      tocListItem.appendChild(tocEntry);
      tocList.appendChild(tocListItem);
    }
    
    toc.appendChild(tocList);
    
    // Create a list for the ToC entries
    tocList = document.createElement("ul");
  }, 1000);
});
```

```
<body>
<div id="ToC"></div>
<div>
    <h3 id="this-is-heading-1">First Heading</h1>
    <p>
        This is paragrah 1
    </p>
    <h3 id="another-heading">Second Section</h1>
    <p>
        This is some words
    </p>
    <h3 id="last-heading">And Finally</h1>
    <p>
        Some more verbiage
    </p>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It would help a lot to see the associated HTML

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of the 1 second delay on the JS? It seems redundant when you're working in a document.ready handler already

Comment: Please make a snippet?

Comment: I have added the html. Please ignore the 1 second delay, it's just because these pages are on a sharepoint site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can go through of each `h3` and get `id` attribute and then create link to corresponding element.

Try this one:

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
            setTimeout(() => {
                // Get ToC div
                
                toc = document.getElementById("ToC"); //Add a header
                tocHeader = document.createElement("h2");
                tocHeader.innerText = "Table of contents";
                toc.appendChild(tocHeader); // Get the h3 tags — ToC entries

                // Create a list for the ToC entries
                tocList = document.createElement("ul");

                $('h3').each(function () {
                    tocListItem = document.createElement("li");
                    // a link for the h3
                    tocEntry = document.createElement("a");
                    tocEntry.setAttribute("href", "#" + $(this).attr('id'));
                    tocEntry.innerText = $(this).text();
                    tocListItem.appendChild(tocEntry);
                    tocList.appendChild(tocListItem);
                });
                toc.appendChild(tocList);
            });
        });
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="ToC"></div>
    <div>
        <h3 id="this-is-heading-1">
            First Heading
        </h3>
        <p>
            This is paragrah 1
        </p>
        <h3 id="another-heading">
            Second Section
        </h3>
        <p>
            This is some words
        </p>
        <h3 id="last-heading">
            And Finally
        </h3>
        <p>
            Some more verbiage
        </p>
    </div>
```